# Behaviors.same vs this

Tags: akka

In akka typed, we have concept of Behavior.

If we want to retain same behaviour by an actor we return Behaviors.same when we are done processing a message. But then we can also return this. How are two different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They work the same. When using the FP:y-style of defining actors you will not have a `this` to return so you can only use `Behaviors.same`.

When defining actors in OO style (extending `AbstractBehavior`) you can use both, but we have tried to consistently use `this` in such samples in the docs and that's the recommendation.

Comment: Thank you, exactly the answer I was looking for